# Close a folder in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I've had a change of file name and also I want to close this folder from the explorer, and also open a new one.

So my requests are:

- How do I close this file and reopen it
- How do I close the folder tab entirely so no folders are opened

Comment: is there no option at the `topbar`? like `file` `edit`

Comment: @debugger no there's none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `File > Close Folder/Workspace`
OR use `Ctrl/Cmd + K F` as keyboard shortcut.

Use `Ctrl + W` to close a file.

Comment: The `Cmd + K` and then `F` worked it. Thank you